# info vars command is not working properly inside a proc

Tags: tcl

I am tring to do some variable auto-completion using TCL (this is intended for jimtcl)

I have tried the following sequence in both tclsh and jimsh:

```
% set VAR1 1
1
% set VAR2 2
2
% info vars  
.... tcl_pkgPath VAR1 tcl_patchLevel VAR2 argc ...
% set pattern \$V*
$V*
% set vars_pattern [string range $pattern 1 end]
V*
% puts [lsort [info vars $vars_pattern]]
VAR1 VAR2
%
```

this is fine.

but once I get this into a proc

```
% proc autocomplete_helper pattern {
    # check for variables auto-completion
    puts "pattern '$pattern'"
    if {[regexp {\$\S+$} $pattern match]} {
        set vars_pattern [string range $match 1 end]
        puts "pattern '$vars_pattern'"
        return [lsort [info vars $vars_pattern]]
    }

    puts "other stuff to do"
}
% autocomplete_helper zerazer
pattern 'zerazer'
other stuff to do
% autocomplete_helper \$V*
pattern '$V*'
pattern 'V*
%
```

do you have any idea why this is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `info vars` command is sensitive to what its current context (obviously; it returns the currently-visible variables) and moving things into a procedure changes that. The *right* fix for this is to use `uplevel` to run the command in a different context, either `uplevel 1` to run in the caller's context or `uplevel #0` to run in the global context (the one at the top of the stack).

In this case, we need to be a little careful because the pattern could have metacharacters in it (it'd be *weird* but legal) and `uplevel` is `eval`-like; the `list` command will ensure we've got a well-formed command. Putting this line into your procedure at the obvious point (everything else unchanged)

```
# The double quotes around #0 are to fool the highlighter used on Stack Overflow
return [lsort [uplevel "#0" [list info vars $vars_pattern]]]
```

With that, I can do this:

```
% autocomplete_helper {$e*}
pattern '$e*'
pattern 'e*'
env errorCode errorInfo
```

Which looks right to me.

Comment: This was originally going to be a comment on @ChrisHeitoff's answer, but I needed more space

Comment: I'm happy you used more space for the explanation.  Thanks for answer.

Comment: well thanks, both of the proposed solutions worked for me. I will opt to use the latest.
that was a very good a quick lecture about namespaces and scope.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This is a namespace problem.

A proc has its own namespace.   When you're running `info vars` at the tclsh prompt, that's the global `::` namespace.

The simplest thing to do in your proc would be to add `::` to your argument to `info vars`

> return [lsort [info vars ::$vars_pattern]]

The return values will include the `::` namespace prefix, so remove that first if you need to.

Funny that you're seeing this problem with an auto-completion application.  I've written a Tcl script to dump out all my procs, commands, namespaces, etc into json files that I read into Vim for a custom auto-completion plugin.   I found the very same problems while writing that.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply ! this works like a charm.
in fact I'm doing an auto-completion for an open source tool named openocd (using jimtcl inside)
I have added the commands auto-completion (ref http://openocd.zylin.com/#/c/6095/),
and now I'm adding the variables auto-completion (ongoing)

Comment: Technically, it's a scope and not a namespace. Namespaces are a type of scope.